# Ingress resource deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio

What is the best approach to create the ingress resource that interact with ELB into target deployment environment that runs on Kubernetes?

As we all know there are different cloud provider and many types of settings that are related to the deployment of your ingress resource which depends on your target environments: AWS, OpenShift, plain vanilla K8S, google cloud, Azure.

On cloud deployments like Amazon, Google, etc., ingresses need also special annotations, most of which are common to all micro services in need of an ingress.

If we deploy also a mesh like Istio on top of k8s then we need to use an Istio gateway with ingress. if we use OCP then it has  special kind called “routes”.

I'm looking for the best solution that targets to use more standard options, decreasing the differences between platforms to deploy ingress resource.

**So maybe the best approach is to create an operator to deploy the Ingress resource because of the many different setups here?**

Is it important to create some generic component to deploy the Ingress while keeping cloud agnostic?

How do other companies deploy their ingress resources to the k8s cluster?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best approach to create the ingress resource that interact with ELB into target deployment environment that runs on Kubernetes?

On AWS the common approach is to use ALB, and the [AWS ALB Ingress Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller), but it has its own drawbacks in that it create *one ALB per Ingress resource*.

> Is we deploy also a mesh like Istio then we need to use Istio gateway with ingress.

Yes, then the situation is different, since you will use `VirtualService` from Istio or use [AWS App Mesh](https://aws.amazon.com/app-mesh/) - that approach looks better, and you will not have an `Ingress` resource for your apps.

> I'm looking for the best solution that targets to use more standard options, decreasing the differences between platforms to deploy ingress resource.

Yes, this is in the intersection between the cloud provider infrastructure and your cluster, so there are unfortunately many different setups here. It also depends on if your ingress gateway is within the cluster or outside of the cluster.

In addition, the [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) resource, just become GA (stable) in the most recent Kubernetes, 1.19.

Comment: Is the right approach is to create k8s sdk operator for any deployment target?

Comment: @TalAvissar creating an operator for deployment sounds like over engineering? But it depends on what your needs are? I would go with a Service Mesh.